# TCP Server/Client - How to send user input and send back the same message from the server?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I want my client to send a message to the server and the server send back the message received
but there is an issue with my client because It never reach the close() statement because of readLine()
therefore it just hangs there, what can I do to make it work ?

Server :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Server{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(3535);
            while(true){
                Socket socket=server.accept();
                BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        
                String message=in.readLine();
                System.out.println(message);

                out.print(message);
                out.flush();
                
                in.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();
            } }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            BufferedReader user_in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while(true){
                Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",3535);
                BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                
                out.print(user_in.readLine());
                out.flush();    

                String message_from_server = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Message from server : " + message_from_server);

                out.close();
                in.close();
                socket.close();
            }
          
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by that it never reaches close

Comment: My current code in client, it takes an user input then send it to the server and then I call  in.readLine() because I want to the receive the message from the server, but because of this call I'm never closing BufferederReader or PrintWriter and it's not sending the message yet. I don't know the reason but when I remove  in.readLine() there is no issue

Comment: Don't vandalize your own posts. If you want to conceal your question, delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem" lies in `readLine()` in the server.

This is wanted behavior. `BufferedReader` implements `readLine()` in a way so that it blocks until it receives either one of: '\n', '\r', carriage return followed by a line feed, or an EOF

The client is sending neither of them.

Instead of using the `print()` method of `PrintWriter`, you could use `println()`.